# Is it possible to connect multiple scorecards to a single analytic chart in PP 2007?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, business-intelligence, performancepoint

I know how to connect a scorecard to a chart in PerformancePoint but I am not sure connecting multiple scorecards is possible by any means?

To connect a scorecard to a chart, I simply place them in the same page and drag and drop a scorecard property to the chart. Then, of course I need configure the connection using MDX.

When I try to drag and drop from a second scorecard to the same chart, it won't allow me. I wonder why and if there is a workaround?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I figured that it is not possible to link multiple scorecards to the same chart. So, I ended up creating multiple charts per scorecard. It is possible to hide charts initially and display them based on certain conditions. You can use the DisplayCondition property on the scorecard to make that happen.